# Which Philosophical Ideas Best Protect Us From Existential Suffering in a Society Increasingly Accepting of the Claim That There is No Free Will?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will, determinism, psychology, philosophy-of-psychology

Discussion of free will seems increasingly prevalent in mainstream media, particularly Youtube and in reputable periodicals such as the Atlantic, the Conversation and the Guardian (to name a few).

Regardless of the 'truth' of Free Will, encountering ideas surrounding determinism and inagency can be difficult to absorb, and in some cases can lead to short-term and potentially long-term serious psychological and interpersonal harm.

As one example, Philosopher Galen Strawson (who denies Free Will) reported to the Guardian that he had been one recipient of a group email which read:

“*Last year you all played a part in destroying my life. I lost everything because of you – my son, my partner, my job, my home, my mental health. All because of you, you told me I had no control, how I was not responsible for anything I do, how my beautiful six-year-old son was not responsible for what he did … Goodbye, and good luck with the rest of your cancerous, evil, pathetic existence*”.

(https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/apr/27/the-clockwork-universe-is-free-will-an-illusion).

The author of the email may have had underlying mental health issues, and whilst such a reaction might be rare, it is clear that the existentialist themes intrinsic to discussion of free will may be psychologically disruptive and/or harmful.

Which philosophical ideas/questions might successfully be employed to help those who find themselves ill-equipped to navigate the psychological pitfalls such as nihilism and moral ambiguity which can accompany investigation of free will?

Comment: Stoicism, of course. "Fate leads the willing, and drags along the reluctant" - Seneca

Comment: That guy lost everything good in his life because some dude said he doesn't believe in free will on TV? Or in a magazine? Somehow I suspect the dude had other issues...

Comment: True. I've now acknowledged this in the question.

Comment: Mr. Parsons take on Non-duality. He can show you how to make money from nothing and demonstrate how it may go back into nothing in a seminar and/or book that are hosted nor written by anyone in particular. It would not surprise me at all if you did not know who I am referring to!

Comment: Funny. After I did my own research on the subject and reached the conclusion that libertarian free will is an illusion, to the contrary it was a relief and made my life easier. Just like when I got rid of my religious beliefs.

Comment: @armand I had a similar 'awakening', but only after a long period of angst. The problem for me - as I suspect it maybe for many - is that they are not aware of or for some reason do not/cannot access - the internal and/or external resources which facilitate a healthy processing of these concepts.

Comment: About this I can't recommend enough Spinoza's Ethics, although it is an hard read, one can concentrate on the scholia parts and grasp the "how I learned to stop worrying and love determinism" idea behind the book. There are also good commentaries by modern authors but unfortunately I know of none published in English.

Comment: I don't think there's any "philosophical" way out of this. Different people will react differently to the belief in no free will... or any other philosophical doctrine. And I don't think any one reaction is more "rational" than another. One person may believe there's no god and despair. Another one might feel happy from the same belief. Maybe from a utilitarian perspective the latter person is in the right. This stuff is more controlled by brain chemistry, genetics etc.

Comment: Maybe it is controlled by people deciding if they are going to believe their own thoughts, or question them? Failure to choose amounts to a de facto choice, so one must actively choose to evaluate, even every unquestioned assumption. It is the choice that matters.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different directions to go on this. The person suffering can study philosophy further and learn to distinguish the implications of propositions more precisely (e.g. come to understand how analytic philosophers' discussions of the problem of free will don't align with popular conceptions of the inefficacy of our actions, or come to understand why whether we have free will or not in the analytic-philosophy sense of the term shouldn't have any effect whatsoever on how we relate to our own sense of agency cognitively, emotionally, or behaviorally; I recommend Dan Dennett's book *Elbow Room* for analyzing some of these distinctions), or they can embrace a deterministic worldview and dive into some life-affirming deterministic philosophy (e.g. stoicism, Spinoza, Nietzsche, Alan Watts), or they can throw those texts in the trash and focus on improving their life instead of externalizing their frustrations about their life onto people who have nothing to do with their life, or they can get professional psychological help to try to untangle these confusions. I do recognize that there is a bastardization of philosophical theories in popular understanding (just like a lot of solid science gets transmuted into pseudoscience serving marketing purposes in many popular publications for laypeople). And there are sociocultural reasons why "determinism" increasingly resonates with more people's firsthand experience of life (e.g. capitalism = the rich get richer and the rest of us have less and less control over our life circumstances). So I'd add Marx to my recommended reading list for people struggling with existential suffering over arguments for determinism. Among other reasons, for Marx's historical materialism: Your ideas are a reflection of your material conditions; so (connecting the Marxist idea to a Nietzschean idea) people don't feel life is meaningless because they're convinced by some philosophy--they're convinced by some philosophy because they feel life is meaningless.

Comment: The last statement is an interesting and persuasive observation. I'm curious about whether psychotherapists may increasingly report presentations related to these issues, and whether these issues come to be explored within compulsory school curriculum. Existentialist psychotherapy (which came to prominence in the '70s - is still taught in tertiary level psychology environments. It may experience a resurgence in professional use –

Answer (score 1):

The claim that there is no free will is a logical paradox. You cannot claim anything, unless you have free will to do so.

People who claim this nonsense are directly responsible for all the harm inflicted to those who believe it. To claim something is a conscious choice. To believe something is not.

The best way to help ill-equipped people is to stop confusing them with paradoxical claims.

Comment: Thanks Pertti. It is not a logical paradox. A person can certainly make a claim, whether or not they have free will. The fact that a person makes a claim says nothing about whether or not they were free to do so. The question is whether or not their claim is determined, or random, or free. When we make a claim, we _experience_ it as free, but there's plenty of evidence to suggest it may not be free at all.  There is probably power in easing people's confusions with a balanced perspective, ie: arguments for free will, but I think that's only part of the solution.

Comment: The claim is determined anyway. A random undetermined claim is not possible or at least it is extremely improbable. Prior events cannot determine the claim, we do not have that complex spinal reflexes. The question is whether it is determined by the claimant himself or by someone else forcing him to make the claim. The question is not whether free will exists, the question is  whose free will is in action.

Comment: You state, "The claim is determined", then "Prior events _cannot_ determine the claim". These two statements are about as contradictory as you can get. Regardless, this conversation is not addressing the question. If you wish to continue, I suggest we move to chat.

Comment: I don't know where to find the chat. This discussion is about my answer and I am defending its validity. Prior events cannot determine the claim, because they were determined by earlier events and they by even earlier, etc. ad inf. The problem with determinism is that the original claimant is never found, not even in theory. The claim must be determined by someone who wants to make that point.

Comment: The persistence with which you bring back this tired fallacy of assuming your own conclusion while being each time corrected on this point is nothing short of astonishing.

Comment: Armand: Please, be more specific. What assumption? What conclusion? What correction?

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/free-will

Comment: I sympathize that people are in some way responsible for the outcomes of their claims. Shouting "Movie" in a crowded firehouse for example. But I feel even more strongly that if we *truly* believe that people have free will, then they are the most responsible for their own taking in, processing and then choosing how (if at all) to act on external info. What happened to teaching kids to be ruthlessly skeptical of anything said by... basically anyone? When did that go out of style, because I used to hear "*Question Authority*", and I reflexively thought: "**Why? They don't have the answers!**"

Comment: When I used to hear those commercials for Amoco that said, "*You expect more from a leader*" I would always think: "**And you DON'T get it!**"

Comment: @Futilitarian I would say that something without free will is not a 'person'. (And I have the Law on my side) So I guess that's the end of the discussion. Non-persons are not allowed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ScottRowe. I think I get what you mean about a being without free will not being a 'person'. It's a tough one. If a being has no free will, they still _experience_ emotions; pain, grief, love, joy etc. They still _experience_ themselves and others as being people, which would ordinarily lend their experience some kind of moral import, but I suppose any morality we afford each other under such a scenario is predetermined anyway, and so is not really morality as we understand it, but the mere impression of morality.

Comment: @Futilitarian I could try for a silly analogy: picture a self-aware, self-driving car, and the same for a train. If the car has a complete brake failure (I watched in my rearview mirror as a car had that happen and slammed in to my car), then *must* the car hit something ahead of it? No, it can steer and hit something else, go in to a guardrail or whatever. If the train has a complete brake failure (impossible, thank you Mr. Westinghouse), *must* it hit something ahead of it? One word answer: Yes. Can we 'steer', or not? One word answer. Final, absolute answer. What is it?

Comment: @ScottRowe. One word just can't do it. If I say 'yes', I am not articulating that this steering may be the result of prior causes. If I say 'no', I am making a series of assumptions about the way causality and determinism work that I realise I (and everyone else) is not equipped to make.  So I can give you a three word answer: 'I don't know'.

Comment: @Futilitarian Fair enough. Perhaps we could all just agree on that answer and move on to more fruitful investigations?

Comment: @ScottRowe. Each to their own. I've been fascinated by it for a while... but I think I'm reaching the point where I'm not going to investigate much further (aside from waiting for the announcements of those who continue to research it). I've reached my interest/motivation-to-investigate-further threshold.  I suppose the biggest impact exposure to determinism theory has had on me is that it has given me greater insight into just how much our supposed free will is actually constrained, which has given me much greater empathy for the predicaments and flaws of others and myself; not a bad outcome.

Comment: @Futilitarian Determinism is not a theory. Determinism*explains* nothing. Free will is constrained only by what you are physically and mentally able to do. You cannot teleport to another place and you cannot choose to do something you cannot even think of.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki. That's interesting Pertti. It certainly explains a lot to me. I agree with you about our free will being constrained by what you are mentally and physically able to do though.

Comment: @Futilitarian Determinism is *by definition* a state of affairs very much different from reality. You cannot explain anything by the *assumption* that free will or randomness don't exist.

Comment: @IPerttiRuismaki. I would never try to fully explain anything based on assumption of anything.

Comment: @Futilitarian But determinism is nothing but an assumption. A simplified model of physical reality to make classical physics easier to understand and calculate.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki. Agreed. It also makes sense at a very simplistic macro level. Eg: I am at the top of the stairs because I climbed the stairs. I try not to let this fact lead me astray when it comes to more complex sequences, although we do know that many physical outcomes are predicatable based on prior circumstances. Eg: exposing air to heat will make it rise etc.